# Bi directional and uni directional in UML, are they objects interacting with other classes?

Tags: java

So I'm learning how to model in UML. I'm currently learning about associations. I think I know what they are but need some clarification.

1) Since associations are links between 2 (or more?) classes, is it right to think that the objects of the classes will be doing the interaction since objects generally interacts with other classes?

2) In bi directional association, both classes know the relationship with each other. For example a class Flight and a class Plane. Flight has a role name of 'assignedFlights' and a multiplicity value of 0...*. Plane has a role name of 'associatedFlight' and a multiplicity value of 0..1. Is it right to say that **objects** of Flight can have 0 or 1 association with the Plane class and Plane objects can have 0 to infinite assocations with the Flight class? And what does it really mean to be '*associated*' with a class? Do they mean something like:
E.g. in plane class, theres a method called `plane();` and in flight class there's a method called `flight();`.

```
class Flight(){
Plane planeObject = new Plane();
planeObject.plane();
// Only one or zero is allowed as a flight instance can only be associated with 1 or 0 planes.
}

class Plane{
Flight flightObject = new Flight();
Flight flightObject2 = new Flight();
Flight flightObjet3 = new Flight();
flightObject.flight();
flightObject2.flight();
flightObject3.flight();
//And so one as a plane can have 0 to infinite associations
}
```

3) Same type of question goes for uni directional association.

Could someone explain to me in layman terms and also in Java as I understand that in Java.

Comment: For q #1, as opposed to static interactions?  Usually it's objects, but sorta depends on the uml diagram and class and design.  Really, it's your design, so a static call to, for e.g. a util class would be denoted as such. For q#2 and #3 you're modelling interactions between objects, so a Plane object (aka instance) is associated to 0 or more Flight objects/instances, and a Flight has an optional association to a Plane object/instance.

Answer (score 0):

Association in Java comes down to the class members of the associated class. So in a way, you had a one-to-many association right in you example. Here's how I'd change it:

```
class Flight(){
Plane planeObject;
// one plane can be associated with a flight
}

class Plane{
List<Flight> flights;
//A plane can be associated with multiple flights
}
```

The arrow direction means navigation. It means, navigability from one object to other. In a bidirectional association, it comes down to both objects having reference to each other. In the above example, `Plane`can navigate to any of the  `flights` and any `Flight` can navigate to associated `Plane` using the class members they have.

In unidirectional, only one object can navigate to the associated object not vice-versa.
Here's an example of uni directional, in which, you can navigate to `Plane` from `Flight`. But from `Flight` object, you can not navigate to `Plane`.

```
class Flight(){
Plane planeObject;
// one plane can be associated with a flight
}

class Plane{

//plane related stuff here
}
```